# Авторизация вконтакте Delphi

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток! В общем пытаюсь авторизоваться вконтакте через Delphi Indy без всякого API ВКонтакте, ну так нужно... Разумеется искал я и нашел просто фантастическое количество способов авторизации, но увы все они уже не актуальны значит нужно сделать свой сначала, думаю все действия лучше производить через http://m.vk.com/ так как основной сайт забит всякими js и ajax query и ещё всякой мутней.

И так что мы имеем? `http://m.vk.com/` форма отправляет `https://login.vk.com/act=login&_orig...ole=pda&utf8=1` причем указан тег novalidate и параметры email и pass всё так просто?

```
Idhttp1.AllowCookies:=true;
Idhttp1.HandleRedirects:=true;

Data:=TstringList.Create;
Data.Add('email='+Edit1.Text);
Data.Add('pass='+Edit2.Text);
Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post(link, Data);
if Pos('Не удается войти', Memo1.Text) <> 0 then
begin
  if Pos('Выход', Memo1.Text) <> 0 then
    Memo2.Lines.Add('Авторизация прошла успешно')
  else
    Memo2.Lines.Add('Ошибка авторизации');
end
else Memo2.Lines.Add(Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность введенных данных');
Data.Free;
```

Но элементарно условия не срабатывают потому что выходит ошибка `IOHandler value is not valid` то есть идёт редирект на https? на мобильной то версии? или что за зло там твориться?

Есть у кого нибудь уже готовый кусок кода простой авторизации ВКонтакте без API ВКонтакте желательно для мобильной версии?

Comment: Используйте API. Это нормальный способ. Иначе Вам постоянно придется переделывать код. Тем более, что со стороны ВКонтакте будут регулярно переделывать (читайте "оптимизировать и улучшать") страницу ввода пароля.

Не рассылку ли особо важных сообщений Вы делаете.

Comment: Можно ли с помощью вашего API вконтакте допустим отправить ЛС пользователю если его у тебя нету в друзьях?

Допустим я получил список пользователей моей группы выбрал одного и отправил ему сообщение (начал переписку)

Думаю топорными методами это реализуется легче...

Comment: API  не мое. Я вообще не пользуюсь вконтактом. не нужен он мне.
И я не знаю, отправлять сообщение другим пользователям, если они у меня не в друзьях (ну разве запрос авторизации).

Answer (score 1):

Самым нормальным и долговечным будет использование этого самого API. Иначе вас ждет ад. 
Далее такие вещи надо руками делать а не в интернете читать, код из сети не вечен и уж точно дольше 2 месяцев - уже хлам(в отношении работы с соц. сетями, без API).

Мобилка определяемся по User-Agent'у браузера, подменяете мобильным и гуляйте по мобильной версии ВК. Далее сниффер вам в руки, чтобы изучать запросы авторизации, и HTML код страницы чтобы 100% узнавать когда правильный ответ, когда нет.

Топорными методами как раз не легче. HTML код вообще строится динамически, и все в нем меняется кроме HTML-стандарта (название тегов и аттрибутов + могут быть собственные аттрибуты). API соц. сети в самый раз.

[API соц. сети здесь.](http://vk.com/dev)